# What Is the Difference Between RDP Copy/Paste and RDC's Mapped Drives?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, file-transfer, copy-paste

Recently I was trying to transfer a file via copying & pasting to a remote computer during a remote desktop session (via Windows Remote Desktop Client). I have done this many times, but it can be spotty if the file is large or the connection is slow. This time especially, the file transfer kept failing (although it wasn't even 1 GB) and the connection would even get dropped entirely, which I think may have been caused by the network load from the file transfer.

Regardless, I searched around and saw that you can map a local drive to a remote computer by going to Local Resources > More > Selecting the drive(s) in the Remote Desktop Connection settings. After I did this and connected to the remote computer again, the drive showed up and I was able to copy the file without any errors. My question is, *why* did that work so much better than a copy/paste before I mapped the drives? Does mapping a local drive in a RDC session use a different transfer method? Or is it no different and I just got lucky? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a different method, one is acting like a mapping network drive and the other is an emulation of the copy/paste functionality made on the spot.
Mapping the local drive is more stable, and more efficient way to maintain that connection.
So both ways are provided for you, one to be easy and fast to use, the other for reliability.